# Compare version numbers in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am using the below to get the file version of a file:

```
sigcheck.exe -n "C:\some.exe"
```

The above returns something like: 12,2,0,6837.

How can I take this version number. Remove the ,'s to make 1 large number & then compare it against another version number which is stored in the name of a txt file such as: 12.3.0.7218.txt (ie do a similar thing to the file version stored in the file name: remove the .'s to make a large number).

I need to be able to perform some code in the batch file if the file that contains the version in its name is later than the applications file version ie install an update.

Comment: If commas & points are removed, you can compare the two numbers? eg. `if %v1% lss %v2% ...`¿

Comment: consider, some version numbers are like `12.13.0.7218` :)

Answer (score 16):

You cannot simply remove the commas (node delimiters) and compare a single number - it may not give the correct result.

For example, 12.3 and 1.23 would both result in 123, leading to a false conclusion of equivalence. You must compare nodes one at a time, starting from the left. As soon as you find a difference in a node, then you have your answer. If the nodes are equivalent until one version runs out of nodes, then the version with more nodes is larger: 1.2.2 > 1.2

**Edit**
Sometimes companies tack on a letter suffix to a node. The letter should be considered a new node. Search and replace can be used to introduce a node delimiter before each letter. Search and replace is case insensitive, so `a` equals `A`.

```
@echo off
setlocal
call :testVersions  2.1      1.9
call :testVersions "2,1"     1-9
call :testVersions  1.9      2.1
call :testVersions  1.13     1.4
call :testVersions  1.4      1.13
call :testVersions  1.3.4    1.3.4
call :testVersions  1.3.4    1.3.5
call :testVersions  1.3.5    1.3.4
call :testVersions  1.3.5    1.3.5.1
call :testVersions  1.3.5.1  1.3.5
call :testVersions  1.3b     1.3
call :testVersions  1.3      1.3b
call :testVersions  1.10a    1.9
call :testVersions  1.9      1.10a
call :testVersions  1.9a     1.9b
call :testVersions  1.9b     1.9a
call :testVersions  1.9a     1.9A
exit /b


:testVersions  version1  version2
call :compareVersions %1 %2
if %errorlevel% == 1 set "result=greater than"
if %errorlevel% == -1 set "result=less than"
if %errorlevel% == 0 set "result=equal to"
echo %~1 is %result% %~2
exit /b


:compareVersions  version1  version2
::
:: Compares two version numbers and returns the result in the ERRORLEVEL
::
:: Returns 1 if version1 > version2
::         0 if version1 = version2
::        -1 if version1 < version2
::
:: The nodes must be delimited by . or , or -
::
:: Nodes are normally strictly numeric, without a 0 prefix. A letter suffix
:: is treated as a separate node
::
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "v1=%~1"
set "v2=%~2"
call :divideLetters v1
call :divideLetters v2
:loop
call :parseNode "%v1%" n1 v1
call :parseNode "%v2%" n2 v2
if %n1% gtr %n2% exit /b 1
if %n1% lss %n2% exit /b -1
if not defined v1 if not defined v2 exit /b 0
if not defined v1 exit /b -1
if not defined v2 exit /b 1
goto :loop


:parseNode  version  nodeVar  remainderVar
for /f "tokens=1* delims=.,-" %%A in ("%~1") do (
  set "%~2=%%A"
  set "%~3=%%B"
)
exit /b


:divideLetters  versionVar
for %%C in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do set "%~1=!%~1:%%C=.%%C!"
exit /b
```

--OUTPUT--

```
2.1 is greater than 1.9
2,1 is greater than 1-9
1.9 is less than 2.1
1.13 is greater than 1.4
1.4 is less than 1.13
1.3.4 is equal to 1.3.4
1.3.4 is less than 1.3.5
1.3.5 is greater than 1.3.4
1.3.5 is less than 1.3.5.1
1.3.5.1 is greater than 1.3.5
1.3b is greater than 1.3
1.3 is less than 1.3b
1.10a is greater than 1.9
1.9 is less than 1.10a
1.9a is less than 1.9b
1.9b is greater than 1.9a
1.9a is equal to 1.9A
```

Answer (score 0):

to convert the commas to [nothing]

```
set sig=12,2,0,6837
set sig=%sig:,=%
echo sig=%sig%
```

to get the filename to a variable, assuming quite a lot, like the name is the lastest in the directory - - don't know the details, sorry - you'll have to be more specific.

```
set "file="
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d *.txt') do if not defined file set file=%%~ni
set file=%file:~.=%
echo %file%
```

but - all depends on HOW you propose to retrieve the filename.

---

so if you use

```
:: you are manually entering NEWVER
SET newver=1230718


for /f %%i in ( ' sigcheck.exe -n "C:\some.exe" ' ) do set sig=%%i
Echo As a check, sig retrieved was %sig%

set sig=%sig:,=%
echo Which gets transformed to sig=%sig%

if %sig% lss %newver% (ECHO New version to be installed
  ) else (echo do not install new version)
```

Now, if you want to execute

```
thisbatch 1230718
```

you can replace

```
SET newver=1230718
```

with

```
SET "newver=%1"
```

and because the `1230718` is the first parameter given to the batch process `thisbatch` `newver` will be set to  `1230718`

Comment: OK thanks for this, lets make is more simply.

If I put the 2nd file version in the batch file instead of reading it, as: 1230718.

So just the first file version to format and then compare

Answer (score 0):

Remove commas:

```
set "v1=12,2,0,6837"
set "v1=%v1:,=%"
```

remove dots:

```
set "v2=12.3.0.7218"
set "v2=%v2:.=%"
```

Answer (score 0):

In cases where the version number syntax matches standard .NET version syntax and PowerShell is available, a fairly compact, legible hybrid .BAT/PowerShell solution is possible:

```
@GOTO :Tests
:CompareVersions
@powershell -command "&{exit(([version]$args[0]).CompareTo([version]$args[1]))}" "%~1" "%~2"
@IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO "%~1" is newer than "%~2")  ELSE (
 IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (ECHO "%~1" is the same as "%~2") ELSE ECHO "%~1" is older than "%~2")
@GOTO :eof

:Tests
CALL :CompareVersions  1.2      1.2.0
CALL :CompareVersions  1.2.3    1.2.3.0
CALL :CompareVersions  1.2.3.4  1.2.3.4
CALL :CompareVersions  1.2.3.4  1.2.4.3
CALL :CompareVersions  1.2.4.3  1.2.3.4
CALL :CompareVersions  1.2.3.4 01.2.3.4
CALL :CompareVersions  9.2.3.4 10.2.4.3
CALL :CompareVersions 01.2.3.4  1.2.3.4
CALL :CompareVersions 10.2.4.3  9.2.3.4
CALL :CompareVersions  1.2.3.4 1.2.03.4
CALL :CompareVersions  1.2.9.4 1.2.10.3
CALL :CompareVersions 1.2.03.4  1.2.3.4
CALL :CompareVersions 1.2.10.3  1.2.9.4
```

The first two cases are there to illustrate a couple of quirky features of standard .NET versions - at least two parts are required and missing parts behave is if they're -1.

I'm not sure about the broader context of the OP's post, but it may be useful to know that, given an .EXE or .DLL, PowerShell can easily extract an IComparable version from the file (e.g. `(Get-Item $fileName).VersionInfo.FileVersionRaw`).